# How can I install jQuery in Rails 7 with importmap?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, import-maps

I have a new Rails 7 application.  I'm currently trying to learn all the new features since Rails 5.  I want to use the following code in my javascript file, but so far I'm getting the following error: `Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined`.

```
$(document).on("turbo:load", () => {
  console.log("turbo!");
});
```

Here are two other relevant files. If I need to post anything else please let me know.

**importmap.rb**

```
pin "application", preload: true
pin "jquery", to: "https://ga.jspm.io/npm:jquery@3.6.0/dist/jquery.js", preload: true
pin "@hotwired/turbo-rails", to: "turbo.min.js", preload: true
pin "@hotwired/stimulus", to: "stimulus.min.js", preload: true
pin "@hotwired/stimulus-loading", to: "stimulus-loading.js", preload: true
pin "el-transition", to: "https://ga.jspm.io/npm:el-transition@0.0.7/index.js"

pin_all_from "app/javascript/controllers", under: "controllers"
```

**application.js**

```
import "@hotwired/turbo-rails"
import "jquery"

$(document).on("turbo:load", () => {
  console.log("turbo!");
});
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Just switch to CDN other than [jspm](https://jspm.org/), *jQuery* will be global on import:

```rb
# config/importmap.rb

# NOTE: pin jquery to jsdelivr instead of jspm
pin "jquery", to: "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery@3.6.0/dist/jquery.js"
```

```js
// app/javascript/application.js

import "jquery"; // this import first
import "script"; // then your other imports that use `$`

// NOTE: don't use relative imports: `import "./script"`
//       add `pin "script"` to `importmap.rb`

console.log($); // ok
```

```
// app/javascript/script.js
console.log($)  // ok
```

Everything just works, one import, multiple imports, jquery plugins. No extra hoisting needed.

---

When using jspm, *jQuery* has to be explicitly imported, where you need it, like any other module:

```js
// app/javascript/place_where_i_need_jquery.js

import $ from "jquery";

// NOTE: don't make jQuery global, this only kind of works.
// window.$ = window.jQuery = $;

console.log($); // ok
```

To clarify and put `window` thing to rest. It works with *stimulus*, because controllers are [imported](https://github.com/hotwired/stimulus-rails/blob/v1.2.1/app/assets/javascripts/stimulus-loading.js#L25) with a dynamic `import()` which usually runs after jquery is loaded and there is time to assign it to *window*, but this is not guaranteed. Which is why you have to do the hoisting thing to ensure `$` becomes global before any other imports.

Comment: Do you mean that different CDNs deliver different versions of a given package? Like `./bin/importmap pin jquery@3.6.3` will give me a different version of jquery than `./bin/importmap pin jquery@3.6.3 --from jsdelivr`? I think I must be misunderstanding something, that doesn't seem right. I feel like I'm taking crazy pills.

Comment: Oh I see they're very different. How does this make sense to anyone

Comment: @FredWillmore `jspm` is for ESM modules. because of the way the module is built/initialized `$` and `jQuery` don't get [exposed](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/3.6.3/src/exports/global.js#L30-L32) globally. I guess there is also some extra processing involved, because this [part](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/3.6.3/src/wrapper.js#L18-L37) is [changed](https://jspm.dev/npm:jquery@3.6.3!cjs) and no more global jquery. (jsdelivr also has esm option, which does the same).

Comment: Voting this WAY UP. Thank you!!!

Comment: `import "script";` => where is script.js supposed to be?

Comment: @raquelhortab `app/javascript/script.js`

Answer (score 8):

Doing what the other answers say will work, but it will stop working when you pin a new package.

The reason is the so-called javascript hoisted way of working, which means that it will reorder the code you have to reorganize the imports in blocks. This will break jQuery window assignation.

To avoid that, extract

```
import jquery from "jquery"
window.jQuery = jquery
window.$ = jquery
```

in another file and call it in on single import.

In my case, I have:

**application.js**

```
import "./src/jquery"

$(function(){
  console.log("Hey!")
})
```

and src/jquery.js with above's code.

Comment: This answer has less upvotes but it's the better answer. This works even with multiple pins. Thx for sharing!

Comment: I'm getting GET http://localhost:3000/assets/src/jquery net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found) when I try to follow this setup

Answer (score 3):

I needed to add a few lines to my **application.js** file.

```
import "@hotwired/turbo-rails"
import jquery from "jquery"
window.jQuery = jquery
window.$ = jquery
```

Comment: apparently we need to do some more setup in order for this to work? Use specific gem/js package?

Answer (score 1):

I tried all of the other suggestions here and none of those worked.

Here is how you solve this:

1. **Pin jquery**
   `bin/importmap pin jquery`
2. **Use jsdelivr.net or local file in importmap.rb**
   *jspm won't work for some unknown reason*
   **a)** `pin "jquery", to: "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery/dist/jquery.js"`
   **b)** `pin "jquery", to: "jquery.js"`
   *if you use a local file, you need to download jquery.js to app/javascript/jquery.js*
   **You can also pin to a specific version if you want that**
   **c)** `pin "jquery", to: "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery@3.7.0/dist/jquery.js"`
3. **In application.js file you only need to add this**
   `import "jquery"`
4. **When you want to use jquery in a view, you *need use type="module" on the script tag***

```
<script type="module">

 $(document).ready(function(){
   console.log($)
 })
</script>
```

Comment: "In application.js file" => which one? the one in /app/assets/javascripts or /app/javascript ?

Comment: @raquelhortab When you create a new Ruby on Rails project you will only have `/app/assets/javascripts/application.js` of those two.