# jQuery is not available after being imported with importmaps

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, import-maps

I am upgrading an old project to Rails 7 with importmaps, and I am having trouble understanding how it's supposed to work now. I have some old JavaScript that relies on jQuery and jquery-ui. I've set it up to import jquery and jquery-ui, but the jQuery variable is not recognized in the jquery-ui module.

importmap.rb:

```
pin "application", preload: true
pin "jquery", to: "https://ga.jspm.io/npm:jquery@3.6.3/dist/jquery.js", preload: true
pin "jquery-ui", to: "https://ga.jspm.io/npm:jquery-ui@1.13.2/ui/widget.js", preload: true
```

application.js:

```
import "jquery";
import "jquery-ui";
```

Here is the error I get:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined
> at widget.js? [sm]:20:11

What am I missing?

Comment: Looks to me like you should either not `preload` application, or you should put application in the end, so jquery is loaded before application.js

Answer (score 2):

To resolve this issue I had to pin jquery using a different CDN:

```
pin "jquery", to: "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery@3.6.3/dist/jquery.js"
```

I'm still struggling to figure out why the different CDNs would deliver a fundamentally different version of jquery with the same version number, but I'm sure it must be my limited understanding of this process. Thanks to user [@Alex](https://stackoverflow.com/users/207090/alex) for this answer:

[How can I install jQuery in Rails 7 with importmap?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72288802/how-can-i-install-jquery-in-rails-7-with-importmap/72290313#72290313)