# Rails 7 importmap with bulma and jquery

Tags: jquery, css, ruby-on-rails, ruby, bulma

I'm having trouble getting Rails 7 importmaps to play nicely with jquery and bulma.

`config/importmap.rb`:

```
pin "application", preload: true
pin "@hotwired/turbo-rails", to: "turbo.min.js", preload: true
pin "@hotwired/stimulus", to: "stimulus.min.js", preload: true
pin "@hotwired/stimulus-loading", to: "stimulus-loading.js", preload: true
pin_all_from "app/javascript/controllers", under: "controllers"
pin "bulma", preload: true # @0.9.4
pin "jquery", preload: true # @3.7.0
pin "jquery-ujs", preload: true # @1.2.3
pin "jquery-ui", preload: true # @1.13.2
```

`application.html.erb`:

```
 <head>
  ...
  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
  <%= csp_meta_tag %>

  <%= javascript_importmap_tags %>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag "application", "data-turbo-track": "reload" %>
  <%= favicon_link_tag asset_path("favicon.png") %>
  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="../images/fav_icon.png" type="image/x-icon">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/bulma-modal-fx/dist/css/modal-fx.min.css" />
  </head>
```

`app/assets/javascripts/application.js`:

```
import "@hotwired/turbo-rails"
import "controllers"
//= require jquery
//= require jquery.turbolinks
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require turbolinks
// require lightbox
//= require_tree .
//= require bulma
```

`app/assets/config/manifest.js`:

```
//= link_tree ../images
//= link_directory ../stylesheets .css
//= link_tree ../javascripts .js
//= link_tree ../../../vendor/javascript .js
//= link controllers/hello_controller.js
//= link controllers/application.js
//= link controllers/index.js
```

`app/javascript/application.js`:

```
import { Application } from "@hotwired/stimulus"
import "controllers"
import "bulma"
import * as jquery from "jquery"
import "jquery-ujs"
import "jquery-ui"

window.jQuery = jquery
window.$ = jquery

const application = Application.start()

// Configure Stimulus development experience
application.debug = false
window.Stimulus = application

export { application }
```

`app/javascript/controllers/index.js`

```
import { application } from "controllers/application"

import { eagerLoadControllersFrom } from "@hotwired/stimulus-loading"
eagerLoadControllersFrom("controllers", application)
```

In the javascript console when I try to load my application, it appears as though the bulma styling is working, but jquery is not.  I'm seeing "Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined" even though I am setting `$` in application.js. There is also another error telling me "Uncaught TypeError: The specifier “controllers/application” was a bare specifier".

[image]

This is my first time working with importmap and I love the idea of being able to cut out npm, webpacker, and yarn, but I'm really having a hard time parsing out how all of these files are supposed to work together.

Answer (score 0):

### Cleanup

You can just make a new rails app to see the setup I'm trying to bring you back to.

Delete this file `app/assets/javascripts/application.js`, can't have two `application.js`.

Already covered by `//= link_tree ../../javascript .js`, so don't need these:

```js
//= link controllers/hello_controller.js
//= link controllers/application.js
//= link controllers/index.js
```

I don't know why you're copying stimulus initialization, it already happens in `controllers` directory.

```js
// app/assets/javascripts/application.js

import "jquery"
import "@hotwired/turbo-rails"
import "controllers"
```

We're using [Turbo](https://turbo.hotwired.dev/), not turbolinks. No Rails UJS in rails 7, and you really don't want to bring that back in.

---

### Jquery

No need to download, just pin it:

```bash
bin/importmap pin jquery -f jsdelivr
```

*https://stackoverflow.com/a/72290313/207090*

### Bulma

Bulma is css:

```html
<!-- app/views/layouts/application.html -->

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bulma@0.9.4/css/bulma.min.css">
```

or import (this is a plain css import that browser should take care of):

```css
/* app/assets/stylesheets/application.css */

@import "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bulma@0.9.4/css/bulma.min.css";
```

### Importmaps

This ends up in the browser in `<script type="importmap">` tag. (see how controllers are already there):

```bash
$ bin/importmap json
{
  "imports": {
    "application":                  "/assets/application-c053fb992232353f27edaf9cd84a9062ed61672b85c0a69952d917f7488ff554.js",
    "@hotwired/turbo-rails":        "/assets/turbo.min-f309baafa3ae5ad6ccee3e7362118b87678d792db8e8ab466c4fa284dd3a4700.js",
    "@hotwired/stimulus":           "/assets/stimulus-1bd52683afde5c8ff5572f5d49429cea5bf7744ca636fcb830c015d8cccf353e.js",
    "@hotwired/stimulus-loading":   "/assets/stimulus-loading-1fc59770fb1654500044afd3f5f6d7d00800e5be36746d55b94a2963a7a228aa.js",
    "jquery":                       "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery@3.7.0/dist/jquery.js",
    "controllers/application":      "/assets/controllers/application-368d98631bccbf2349e0d4f8269afb3fe9625118341966de054759d96ea86c7e.js",
    "controllers/hello_controller": "/assets/controllers/hello_controller-549135e8e7c683a538c3d6d517339ba470fcfb79d62f738a0a089ba41851a554.js",
    "controllers":                  "/assets/controllers/index-16af318b40862c438fd6ca780240ce4730b8591e53dc53315b75f360435cf905.js"
  }#    ^                             ^
}  #    |                             |
   #  names you use to import        urls browser uses to get it
   #    |                             ^ 
   #    |                             |
   #    `------>  mapped to  ---------'
```

This json is what you're building with `pin` and `pin_all_from` commands in `config/importmap.rb`. If you don't see something there you can't import it, unless you're using full urls:

```js
import "jquery";
// works, because it is mapped to a jsdelivr url

// without an import-map you can do this
import "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery@3.7.0/dist/jquery.js";
```

Same thing for your local files, they have to be mapped, or in rails terms pinned. That process goes through `sprockets` to locate files. But I think I've covered it here:

*https://stackoverflow.com/a/72855705/207090*