# rails 7.1.3 doesn't execute application.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, materialize

Hi everyone i've been using rails 7.1.3 and i faced some problem in javascript side where application.js does compile my jquery please if you can help me about that i will be greatfull  iv'e been using rails 7.0.5 and i didn't have any issue byt for rails 7.1.3  the application.js the jquery part is not executed thanks [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/58nHM.jpg)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OPXq4.jpg)[[enter image description here(https://i.stack.imgur.com/t6DNL.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I5QCz.png)iv'e tried to use script javascript inside html and it's work fine but i need to execute application.js with jquery thanks

Comment: Don't use images in your question -- https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode

Comment: you don't have `main.js` file to import.

Comment: how can i import main.js thanks for your answer

Comment: where exactly is that file?

Comment: main.js inside custom folder inside javascript folder

Comment: /app/javascript/custom

Comment: i've tried with application.js and it's not working too

Comment: but when i include javascript in application.html.erb it's work fine so the problem is the javascript file it's not compiled

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to `pin` your files and then `import` them:

```rb
# config/importmap.rb

pin_all_from "app/javascript/custom", under: "custom"
```

```js
// app/javascript/application.js

import "custom/main"
```

*https://stackoverflow.com/a/72855705/207090*

---

For *jquery*, here is how to set it up:

*[How can I install jQuery in Rails 7 with importmap?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72288802/207090)*

Also, I'd suggest you stop with the inline scripts as well.